# Is it possible to get a South African visa in the US without visiting the consulate?

Tags: visas, south-africa, san-francisco, chinese-citizens, spouses

We want to visit SA together after getting married.

From what I've heard, Chinese (PRC) citizens need to get a visa in person at the SA consulate. Unfortunately we live in San Francisco and the nearest SA consulate (Los Angeles) is 6 hours drive away.

Any alternatives to a tourist visa for a spouse of a South African citizen, other than visiting the consulate?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the consulate's website](http://www.southafrica-newyork.net/homeaffairs/tourist_visa.htm), you must apply in Person:

> Effective 10 May 2015, applicants for visas will be required to apply in person at the South African mission.  No appointment necessary.

[VisaCentral](http://visacentral.com/), the leading global visa agency, confirms the same.

A Tourist visa is the option for you, unless you want to move there, in which case a relative's residence permit is your best option.